# Can I somehow convert my Python script to Arduino?

Tags: python, arduino, arduino-ide

I created a voice assistant program in Python which I would like to move into the Arduino IDE for another project. Is there a way to convert a python file to an ino file or something like that?

Comment: [This doesn't convert, but might work for you](https://realpython.com/arduino-python/)

Comment: @Dion Thanks for that, that really helped me with getting started. Thanks